# Passing the values token and user email from the direct line website to the bot to authenticate it

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am passing the below values to my bot from the web site channel (direct line). How do I receive these values in the bot ? can you some one please explain ?

```
 <script>
  window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: '@Model.Token' }),
        userID: '@Model.UserId'
  }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
</script>
```

Thanks,
Selva

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get either of those values (or any others, for that matter), then you should send the data via `channelData`. You can do so a couple different ways via Web Chat's `store`:

**1) DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY** - In this example, if an activity is posted that also includes the text "send user details" (i.e. a card button is pressed that also displays text to the user), then `userId` and `userDetails` will be appended and sent as `channelData` data points. In this case, only the message (or postBack, etc.) activity is received by the bot. (Sample reference [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggy-back-on-outgoing-activities).)

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simple-update-in/dist/simple-update-in.production.min.js"></script>

const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
    if(action.payload.activity && action.payload.activity.text) {
      let text = action.payload.activity.text.toLowerCase();
      if(text === 'send user details') {
        const userId = 'xyz789';
        const userDetails = { 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 35, 'features': { 'eyes': 'brown', 'hair': 'blonde' }};
        action = window.simpleUpdateIn(
          action,
          ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData'],
          () => ({
            'userId': userId,
            'userDetails': userDetails
          })
        )
      } 
    }
  }

  return next( action );
} );
```

** 2) WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT** - In this example, again, if an activity is posted that also includes the text "send user details", then a separate event activity is produced and sent simultaneously that then includes both `userId` and `userDetails` as `channelData` data points. In this case, two activities are received by the bot: a message (or postBack, etc.) activity and an event activity. (Sample reference [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event).)

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
    if(action.payload.activity && action.payload.activity.text) {
      let text = action.payload.activity.text.toLowerCase();
      if(text === 'send user details') {
        const userId = 'xyz789';
        const userDetails = { 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 35, 'features': { 'eyes': 'brown', 'hair': 'blonde' }};
        dispatch( {
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
            value: {
              userId,
              userDetails
            }
          }
        } )
      }
    }
  }

  return next( action );
} );
```

In both cases, for simplicity, the activity only posts when an incoming activity contains the text "send user datails". Also, note that I am demonstrating two ways of utilizing the store: indirectly and directly calling `dispatch()`.

Hope of help!